# Fixed Header Scrollable Table inside Repeater

Tags: asp.net, css

I found a simple css solution to have an `html table` with scrollable `<tbody>` and fixed `<thead>` which I find very nice. This is the source: [Source](http://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/oswdB)

Now, I applied the same css to my `asp:Repeater` but there seems to be a little problem though it works perfectly if table is not inside a repeater.

[image]

This is the css I used:

```css
<style type="text/css">
div.tableContainer{
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
html>body div.tableContainer{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;    
    border: 1px solid black;
}
thead.fixedHeader tr{
    position: relative;
}
thead.fixedHeader th{
    background: yellow;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent{
    display: block;
    height: 245px;    
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
html>body thead.fixedHeader{
    display: table;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
tbody.scrollContent td{
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 50px;
}

/* column widths */
 tbody tr:first-of-type .four{
     width: 4%;
 }
 tbody tr:first-of-type .five{
     width: 5%;
 }
 tbody tr:first-of-type .six{
     width: 6%;
 }
 tbody tr:first-of-type .eight{
     width: 8%;
 }
 tbody tr:first-of-type .seventeen{
     width: 17%;
 }
</style>
```

..and this is how the `asp:Repeater` coded:

```html
<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <%--<table id="tbl-content" width="95%" class="tftable">
                                    <thead>--%>                            
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <thead class="fixedHeader">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="4%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>#</strong></th>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="8%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>CID</strong></th>
                                           <th rowspan="2" width="17%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="5%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Gender</strong></th>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="5%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Age</strong></th>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="5%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>XX</strong></th>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="5%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>XX</strong></th>
                                            <th rowspan="2" width="5%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>XX</strong></th>
                                            <th colspan="11" width="46%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>XX</strong></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">A</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">B</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">C</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">D</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">E</th>                                            
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">F</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">G</th>                                            
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">H</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">I</th>
                                            <th width="4%" style="text-align:center;">J</th>
                                            <th width="6%" style="text-align:center;">K</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="scrollContent">                                    
                              </HeaderTemplate>
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" class="four"><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
                                            <td align="left" class="eight">Data 1</td>
                                            <td align="left" class="seventeen">&nbsp;<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FULLNAME")%></td>
                                            <td class="five"><center><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GENDER")%></center></td>
                                            <td class="five"><center><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AGE")%></center></td>
                                            <td class="five"><center>Data</center></td>   
                                            <td class="five"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="five"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</center></td>
                                            <td class="four"><center>Data</td>
                                        </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>                            
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
```

The `<tbody>`'s width is already set in 100% but it doesn't extend to the end of `div` though the scroll positioned right *(there's a little white space after the last column of the tbody and before the scroll)*. I tried to change the display css setting of `html>body tbody.scrollContent` but I still can't extend the `<tbody>`. Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: Instead of link of codepan,  you have pasted image link. Update that please.

Comment: place your header outside to repeater and fix the width equal to repeater itemtemplate column.

Comment: @Amit already did. not working

Comment: Place a div before <div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer"> and structure a table with column as you place within repeater control . then tableContainer will scroll and header column div will static.